# Internal server error on node save

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm getting internal server error on node save.

In `db log messages` there is no such error regarding this issue.

In apache error log I have these messages

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds, referer: http://test.com/node/add/photos
[error] Premature end of script headers: php-fcgi-wrapper, referer: http://test.com/node/add/photos
```

Comment: Something is timing out. Guessing from the URL, is there some photo processing going on? Similar: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers

Comment: which browser are you using.

Comment: it was happening on every browser. the issue was in search api. it has been fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely caused by a rather long script that was timing out. The `IPCCommTimeout` on your virtual server is set to 40 seconds. If you encounter this problem again, you could edit the Apache directives that apply to this virtual server in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf` and set IPCCommTimeout, for example, to 300.

If you are using Virtualmin

- Chose the virtual server that you want to edit from the drop-down
  menu
- Go to Services -> Configure Website -> Edit Directives
- Modify IPCCommTimeout from 40 to, for ex. 300 (seconds)